# Operator precedence with cout and pointers

Tags: c++

Confused about the output for the second code snippet. Why is the output different than the first program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int s[5] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5};

    int *p = s;

    int first = *(p++);
    int second = *++p;
    int third = ++*p;
    int fourth = *p++;

    cout << "*p++ is " <<  first << endl
         << "*++p is " << second << endl
         << "++*p is " << third << endl
         << "*p++ is " << fourth << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### output:

```
*p++ is 1
*++p is 3
++*p is 4
*p++ is 4
```

https://ideone.com/Qu2uIJ

I expected the output would be the same in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int s[5] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5};

    int *p = s;

    cout << "*p++ is " << *p++ << endl
         << "*++p is " << *++p << endl
         << "++*p is " << ++*p << endl
         << "*p++ is " << *p++ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### output:

```
*p++ is 3
*++p is 3
++*p is 3
*p++ is 1
```

https://ideone.com/nwd7xR

What's going on?

Comment: This is UB before C++17.

Comment: This is nothing to do with operator precedence, it is to do with the order in which the expressions in that statement are executed.  Code like this is always dangerous, unless what you are doing is well-defined and you understand it properly.

Comment: Irrespective whether this is UB or not: one should avoid such code altogether in order to make it more readable and avoid confusion for others and one self in the future.

Comment: @PaulSanders -- are you referring to using splitting a statement up over multiple lines? I'm unsure of exactly which aspect of the code is being referred to.

Comment: @Jodocus ^^  see comment above    ^^

Comment: No, doing that is fine.  It's using ==p or p++ multiple times in the same statement and expecting to do what _you_ happen to think it will do that is risky.  If you do that, you have to be sure of your ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement `cout << "*p++ is " <<  *p++ << endl  << ...;` is treated as one expression, and C++ is almost free in the order of evaluating the arguments used in expressions. SO it is undefined (behaviour actually) in which order the `p++` and `++`-statements are evaluated.

In the first approach, evaluation order is according to the variables to which you assign. In the second, C++ is free (and treats it as UB if there is no sequence point in the expression; in your's, there isn't a sequence point).

Comment: Is this something that would be fixed by using a c++17 mode with its changes to the rules about order of evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

As per operator precedence, operator << is left to right which occurs in cout object in sequence one after the other and sequence of evaluation of arguments to operator << is unspecified.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As mentioned in one of the comments, the OP's problem isn't due to operator precedence. If you still think that this answer's the question, care to add details to why and how it solves it and support it with useful links!

Answer (score 0):

> Between consecutive "sequence points" an object's value can be
>   modified only once by an expression.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx

**The second code snippet attempts to modify the pointer's value multiple times within one sequence.**

List of C Sequence Points:

- Left operand of the **logical-AND operator (&&).**
- Left operand of the **logical-OR operator (||).**
- Left operand of the **comma operator (,)**
- Function-call operator  **()**
- First operand of the **conditional operator** aka **ternary operator** ( **? :** )
- The end of a full **initialization expression** (that is, an expression
  that is not part of another expression such as the end of an
  initialization in a declaration statement).
- The **expression in an expression statement**. Expression statements
  consist of an optional expression followed by a semicolon (**;**). The
  expression is evaluated for its side effects and there is a sequence
  point following this evaluation.
- The controlling **expression in a selection (if or switch)** statement.
- The controlling **expression of a while or do** statement.
- Each of the **three expressions of a for** statement.
- The expression in a **return** statement.